# PDF to array of Pages

Tags: javascript

Suppose we receive a PDF using the following code

```
let pdfDocument = await PDFJS.getDocument(currentPdf.path);
```

Now can we create an array of Pages of the PDF so that we can apply async call (**forEach**) over the array ?

Let's consider we have a PDF of 6 pages. I want to have an array of 6 pages. We can access each page by pdfDocument.getPage(index) but I want to have a whole array.

Comment: Are you referring to the mac app `Pages` ? What library are you using?

Comment: No, let's consider we have a PDF of 6 pages. I want to have an array of all the pages. We can access each page by `pdfDocument.getPage(index)` but I want to have a whole array.